# Exclude specific file from Windows Defender command line

Tags: windows, anti-virus, powershell, cmd.exe

I want to know how to exclude a specific file or file extension from Windows Defender from the command line. Does anyone have experience with this?

I want to know either how to exclude a file from Windows Defender or just allow the application through Windows Defender so it wouldn't get scanned in the command line.

Thank You

Comment: Have you looked any of this up? There are reference manuals. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/Add-MpPreference?view=win10-ps

Comment: thank you i fixed it schroeder da mastah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath" command in Powershell

Example in Powershell:

```
 PS C:\> Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath "C:\Temp"
```

This command adds the folder C:\Temp to the exclusion list. The command disables Windows Defender scheduled and real-time scanning for files in this folder.

[Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/defender/Add-MpPreference?view=win10-ps)

PS, thanks scroeder

Comment: If you get the error `Add-MpPreference: Operation failed with the following error: 0x%1!x!` it probably means you're not in an Admin shell.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a way to exclude a FILE with PS, only a folder, extension or a process.

In the UI you can select:

- file
- folder
- extension
- process

But the Add-MpPreference documentation only lists:

- [-ExclusionPath <String[]>]
- [-ExclusionExtension <String[]>]
- [-ExclusionProcess <String[]>]