# How to exclude specific shadow copy files or folders from Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-defender

I have some utilities purposefully installed on my computer that Windows Defender detects as malware/hacking tools and wants to remove. I've successfully added them to the exclusion whitelist via

*Control Panel >> Virus & threat protection >> Manage Settings >> Add or remove exlcusions*

[image: folder C:\apps\NirSoft]

I am no longer plagued by notifications about virus threats for these files. However I am still being spammed about these same files in the ShadowCopy. How do I whitelist files or folders from both the primary volume and the shadowcopy? The *[Add an Exclusion]* button doesn't allow me to use the path reported by Defender in the threat notification:

```
file: \Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy35\apps\NirSoft\netpass.exe
```

Comment: What is "ShadowCopy" in this case?

Comment: Similar question>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/1416767/exclude-specific-file-from-windows-defender-command-line/1416773#1416773

Comment: @harrymc https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy

Comment: @Moab thanks! I used that to add the shadow folder to exclusion list but I'm still getting notifications. I'm now trying various wildcard combinations. I think I might need to figure out what the fully qualified SC path is (e.g. what goes before `\Device`)

Comment: Or just turn off checking for "potentially unwanted application", https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/potentially-unwanted-app-found-message/ . Though it might decrease security slightly, most of these warnings are for useful tools, such as some of the Nirsoft's suite.

Comment: OK, understood. This won't work for example if you have symbolic links to files outside of the VSS folders. It would be much simpler, if your computer is now clean, to delete them all.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik yeah I don't want to lose the "unwanted application" protection layer completely. I just want to tell the guard at the door: "See this person? She's my friend, let her in without hassle. Thanks."